# syncing local file to github repo

Tags: git, github, synchronization

Beginner question/problem. I used Git to commit a file to a repo on Github and used git show to confirm that it had been successful, but I'm unable to see the file on GitHub. Why is that? Are there any simple instructions for syncing up a file to GitHub that I could use to verify or indicate that it was pushed to GitHub?

Comment: I'm not a GitHub expert, but there could be a delay of some minutes.  I have seen a delay in BitBucket before.  Also, you could have done something wrong.

Comment: Probably the branch on which you pushed and the branch you are checking are different

Comment: Did you `push`? `commit`is local, `push` sends it to your git server. Check 1615903's excellent answer.

Answer (score 3):

> I used Git to commit a file to a repo on Github

You don't commit files directly to a repo on GitHub, you make commits in your local clone and then push those commits to remote repository, in this case GitHub.

> ... used git show to confirm that it had been successful

`git show` does not tell you if the push has been successful or not, it just shows the contents of the last commit.

> I'm unable to see the file on GitHub. Why is that?

Did you do a `git push`?

> simple instructions for syncing up a file to GitHub

You don't sync files with git, you work with commits. You use `git push` to push local commits to a remote, and `git pull` or `git fetch` to get commits from a remote to your local repo.

> verify or indicate that it was pushed to GitHub?

The output of `git push` tells you if the push succeeded or not.

Answer (score 0):

Are u pushing directly to the master branch?

you can always do a git shortlog to see your commits for accuracy.
Add a limit to the number of commits.

e.g. git shortlog -10 will give you the last 10 commits that have been pushed to the remote.

Or maybe your local branch's refs do not point to the remote branches refs? Try a git fetch and then a git push --set-upstream

This will set the remote branch to hold everything you push from your local branch.