# how to push a file from local branch to remote branch

Tags: git

1. I have a local branch name mydev and remote branch name mydev
2. I made change to a file and commit this file to my local branch mydev
   How do I push this file from my local branch mydev to my remote branch mydev and also update the master branch? Thanks

Comment: `git push origin mydev` shall do it for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [syncing local file to github repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254610/syncing-local-file-to-github-repo)

Answer (score 0):

First push to 'mydev' branch. Then switch to 'master' branch and marge 'master' with 'mydev'. Now push to remote master.

```
git push origin mydev
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff mydev
git push origin master
```

[Here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) is a great article on Git branching model.